# which is a good practice to use access function

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc

I have the following code that I want to work also on Linux with GCC 4.8

This is working with VS 2013

```
if ( _access( trigger->c_str(), 0 ) != -1 ) 
{
   ...
}
```

I know that on Linux I can use function: access from "unistd.h"

Is there a way to avoid having something like the following ( a more elegant solution ) ?

```
#ifdef __linux__ 
    #include <unistd.h>
#endif

#ifdef __linux__ 
     if ( access( trigger->c_str(), 0 ) != -1 ) 
     {
          ...
     }
#else
     if ( _access( trigger->c_str(), 0 ) != -1 )
     {
          ...
     }
#endif
```

Comment: Interestingly enough, [MSDN considers `access` deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235395.aspx).

Comment: ... and I get grief when I state that Microsoft treats C++ as a second-class citizen. The proposition that `access()` is deprecated is silly on its face value.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik They seem to have a good reason for that.

Comment: Well, they say they do. I say that the last time I checked `access()` is still very much a part of POSIX, and is deprecated only inside Microsoft's reality distortion field.

Comment: `access()` is not a standard C++ function anyway.   It is POSIX.  Microsoft's statement that is is deprecated refers to it being deprecated in their products, not that it is deprecated from the standard.    The fact it is not in the C++ standard means they are not obligated to support it (assuming they are willing to accept moans from developers who insist they should) - and their support of POSIX has always been (um) selective.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, `access` has nothing to do with C++ whatsoever.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A solution that has no duplication, nor relies on a macro definition (besides the predefined one for platform detection) but has slightly more boilerplate than Aracthor's solution:

```
#ifdef _WIN32 
    inline int access(const char *pathname, int mode) {
        return _access(pathname, mode);
    }
#else
#include <unistd.h>
#endif
```

I prefer to detect windows, and use posix as fall back, because windows tends to be the exception more often than linux.

Another clean solution would be to define [`_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_WARNINGS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ef0s5kh.aspx) and keep using the POSIX standard `access` in windows, without warnings about deprecation. As a bonus, this also disables warnings for using the standard `strcpy` instead of `strcpy_s` and similar. The latter is also standard (in C11), but optional and hardly any other C library implements them (and also, not all of the `_s` family functions in msvc comply to C11).

Answer (score 3):

There is another way, header-only solution.

```
#ifdef __linux__ 
    #include <unistd.h>
#else
    #define access _access
#endif

if ( access( trigger->c_str(), 0 ) != -1 ) 
{
      ...
}
```

It would include the right file on Linux systems and replace `access` with `_access` on other systems.

Comment: Thank you. This makes it cleaner.

Comment: Does similar functionality exists as part of std::filesystem library?